# What is the conventional way to modify an element wheras a Screenreader(ex:Jaws, VoiceOver) can 'read it'?

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, screen-readers

Since screenreaders basically ignore Javascript files, in order for a ScreenReader to read an element that initially can't be read (ex: div), how can I modify the tags, or what attributes will make it readable?

```
<div id="myUnreadableDiv> Screen reader read something outloud </div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA

Answer (score 3):

**Modern screen readers do not ignore javascript.**

You have nothing to do if you want a `div` initialized by some javascript code to be readable.

You can also indicate your browser of changes done in javascript by using `aria-live` attribute.